# Azure App Gateway to respond with 403.4 when HTTP used

Tags: azure-application-gateway

Is there a way to get App Gateways (v1 or v2) to respond with 403 (or 403.4) when an HTTPS only resource is accessed through HTTP?

Redirect is not desired.

Right now, my requests just time out:

```
curl -G -v "http://my-custom-domain/v1/api" --data-urlencode "username=myusername" --data-urlencode "password=secret" --data-urlencode "api-client-key=some-key"
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying xx.xxx.xx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:20 --:--:--    0* connect to xx.xxx.xx.xxx port 80 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to my-custom-domain port 80: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-custom-domain port 80: Timed out
```

Comment: What do you mean "an HTTPS only resource is accessed through HTTP?"  is this the listener HTTPS and the http settings HTTP? What about backend health on your side?

Comment: What I meant to say was a resource to which I'd only want HTTPS access.

Comment: If you only allow HTTPS, why do you test with port 80 instead of 443? What is your backend health status in your application gateway?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm making myself clear. I'm exposing a resource and I want others get "403.4" back when they hit it through HTTP so that they know this resource is only available through HTTPS. Basically I'd want to adhere to RFC's spec and communicate back a proper response code if someone tries to access the resource through HTTP. I'm not sure how the backend health is relevant here.